# Getting different timestamp(epoch time) locally and remotely while using LocalDateTime in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, epoch, docker-container, localdate

I am printing Epoch time using LocalDateTime like this

```
System.out.println("timestamp "+LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

So whenever I run this piece of code locally in Intellij I get the proper timestamp with the Kolkata timezone which is approx `1559461130527`. This is around `Sunday, June 2, 2019 1:23:50.527 PM` Kolkata time

Then I have a server with docker container and whenever I run this same piece of code there I get a totally different timestamp which is approx `1559439902340`. This is around `Sunday, June 2, 2019 7:30:02.340 AM`.

What am I missing, isn't the server supposed to print the timestamp according to the specified time zone. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the zone offset in the now() statement.

For example to get UTC time I use `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);`

In your case you can use directly the ZoneId for your time zone

`LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the implementation of `LocalDateTime::now` method which looks like :

```
public static LocalDateTime now() {
    return now(Clock.systemDefaultZone());
}
```

So it will use `Clock` implementation default for your system. Probably you are using different operating system in your container and that is why there will be different default clock used.

So `LocalDateTime::now` method invocation, in yor case, will return different values depending on system default `Clock`. And then if you want to convert it to `ZonedDateTime` using `atZone` method - you will have different times in the same zone - because `LocalDateTime::now` returned different values for different default clocks in different operating systems.

To overcome this you could use `ZonedDateTime` class directly and passing zone to `now` method :

```
ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```